# Best index choice for Boolean type in OrientDB

Tags: indexing, boolean, query-optimization, orientdb

I'm setting a flag on my records to see which ones have already been processed by my import script, and am wondering what [type of index](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Indexes) I should use. My thought is to use `NOTUNIQUE_HASH_INDEX`. Is that best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends by what you need. All *_HASH_INDEX types are super fast but don't allow range queries like:

```
select from Invoice where date between '2014-01-01 00:00:00.000' and 
                                       '2014-12-31 00:00:00.000'
```

While classic index (sb-tree) can do it. About UNIQUE and NOT-UNIQUE depends if you can have duplication against the indexed fields. Like RDBMS.

Comment: my case is specifically for Booleans. I don't need range queries so I'm trying `NOTUNIQUE_HASH_INDEX` but am wondering if that's the best solution because booleans are  can only have 2 values versus other data types people usually index.

Comment: Booleans could be treated as special case by optimizing space and management, but now are managed like other properties.